# winform c# Error 1 'MyGame.MainForm' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

The error I got:

```
error on line 18 (Applicaiton.Run(new MainForm());
winform c# Error 1 'MyGame.MainForm' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

how can it be fixed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyGame
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm()); here is where the error is
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the error should tell you exactly what you need to do. You're trying to create the object using a constructor that takes 0 arguments. You don't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments. What do you think the solutions might be?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a *parameterless* constructor to your `MainForm`.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // don't forget to call InitializeComponent.
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: public MainForm(DataRow row)
        {
            editRow = row;
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateForm();
        }

Comment: that is not a **parameterless** constructor

Comment: @StillBlessed that is not a parameterless constructor. It has a parameter in the signature. `DataRow row`